# How to dynamically add Class to progress bar

Tags: jquery

I am trying to put dynamic class to my progress bar,and this progress bar is added dynamically also to my table

this is my progressbar added dynamically.

```
<div class='progress'>
              <div class='progress-bar' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='60' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100'>

               </div>
             </div>
```

Comment: so what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#downloadlist').addClass('myClass');
});
```

That will add a class to the table. Use the same logic to add it to the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery this is quite easy.

```
$("#downloadlist").addClass("ClassNameYouWantToAdd");
```

Also check out the documentation
[from JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)